# in stock price prediction should we take the sign of the prediction as another variable

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, prediction, stock

I am predicting stock price of a company , I have used everyday changes in time series, but the negative changes are needed and I cant use log transformation on it. So is it ok if I model the sign as one more variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you normalize and have a single variable, time-series has the property to take care of crests and troughs . There wont be any need of having the signs.

I faced this same dilema sometime back. I figured its not that needed unless you want to give pointer on weather the prices will go up or down also in future.Otherwise no.

Can you give a more clear picture on whats the objective and what data are you considering !